# How to keep AdSense ads from appearing on my uploaded YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

I don't have a Google AdSense account and I haven't checked "monetize" for my YouTube video channel, but videos I upload and then embed into web pages play with Google AdSense ads.  How can I stop this?

Thanks